# Where is the MySQL JDBC jar file in Ubuntu?

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu

I have installed MySQL 5.5.32 via `apt-get install` into Ubuntu 13.04.I want to use it in a Java project.For this i must have MySql connector jar.I can not find it.I tried `locate *mysql*.jar` but it did not find anything.I looked into `/etc/mysql` but there is no jar in it.**I don't want to download it from internet** because i believe that it somehow exists in an MySQL folder.Does anybody have any idea where the connector jar went into Ubuntu 13.04?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

If you're using a version of Ubuntu prior to 19.04, you'll need to install **libmysql-java**, the MySQL JDBC driver, because the connector is not in the Ubuntu-packaged MySQL package that you've already installed. Versions after that do not publish that package.

Once it's installed, you'll have the file `/usr/share/java/mysql.jar`, which is an indirect symlink to the actual jar file.

Alternatively, install the [mysql-apt-config](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/repo/apt/) package, update, and you'll be able to install all currently supported MySQL software with `apt`.

Comment: ubuntu 19.10: E: Unable to locate package libmysql-java

Comment: It seems Ubuntu only ships this package with 16.04 and 18.04 LTS at this time.

Comment: while the path is correct, even now, the file name may be different ex: /usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java-8.0.23.jar

Answer (score 42):

First, `apt-get install libmysql-java`

Then `mysql.jar` is located in `/usr/share/java/mysql.jar`.

Third, in Eclipse, do this as: Project -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries -> Add External JARs -> select `/usr/share/java/mysql.jar`

Comment: Project > Properties > Java Build Path > Libraries (tab) > Add External Jars, just to spell it out completely

Answer (score 9):

In ubuntu 19.10 the following works:

```
apt-get install libmariadb-java
```

Comment: for ubuntu 20 too ? how can i check if my ubuntu have already mysql-connector-java ?

Comment: MariaDB is MySQL-compatible, to a certain point. It *should* work.