# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver exception in linux and text editor

Tags: java, mysql, linux, database, jdbc

My code looks like this-(working in normal text editor)

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

class JDBCTest {

    private static final String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/learn";

    private static final String user = "root";

    private static final String password = "B!SHu12345";

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");  
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
        Statement st=con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select * from bishu where id =101");
        while(rs.next()){
            String s=rs.getString("id");
            System.out.println(s);  
        }
            System.out.println("Success");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
       System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

At run time it gives an exception as follows-

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
 at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
 at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
 at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:195)
 at JDBCTest.main(first.java:14)
```

Mysql connector was downloaded and saved in the path- `Java/jre1.8.0_91/lib/ext/`

I have gone through many similar solutions available, but wasn't able to find a valid one.

Comment: Where are you running `java` from?  If from a JDK directory, I think the MySQL connector should be placed there, not in the JRE folder.

Comment: Add the jdbc driver to your classpath using command prompt.

Comment: You should add third party libraries in a folder inside your project. Then add them directly to the classpath or create a library with them. So it's more comfortable to work with.

Comment: Yeah, I tried it using inside JDK/lib directory, still it doesn't work. I am not able to understand where to place my mysql-connector-java-5.1.43 folder and set the class path.

Comment: You should not put stuff in the JDK `lib` or `lib/ext` folders.

Comment: Could you please tell where should I put mysql-connector-java-5.1.43 folder? and set which classpath?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the MYSQL JDBC Driver from the library of your IDE.or place this JDBC driver file inside the lib directory of your project. Your question looks similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18128966/where-is-the-mysql-jdbc-jar-file-in-ubuntu) question

Comment: I am not using any IDE, I'm working on normal text editor

Comment: try the link in answer, please.

Comment: Still, It's not working. I'm not able to locate the installed file and the exception continues